# Preventing the * and # keypress on iOS keypad in tel mode

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I'm trying to only allow the digits 0-9 to be entered in an HTML input element by using the keydown event in JavaScript for browsers on an iOS device. I have an event handler setup on the keydown event for the input element and it is preventing the inputs I don't want with the exception of the * and #. The input element is of type tel so it brings up the iOS telephone keypad which includes the * and # as options. When I debug the code the keyCode values are coming into the event with * = 56 and #= 51 but 56 is also assigned to the number 8 key and 51 is also assigned to the number 3 key. 
Is there a property of the event that I should be looking at to determine if is truly 0-9?

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9vmb02ku/4/)

```
NumericInputValidator.allowedKeys = [ 8, 35, 36, 37, 39, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried this?

`<input type="tel" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" title="Non-negative integral number">`

Most browsers should be able to read this. I think Android may have an issue but if you're not worried about that or if you JS can handle that then it should be ok.

http://danielfriesen.name/blog/2013/09/19/input-type-number-and-ios-numeric-keypad/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to stick with the tel type as it restricts the user to a more limited set of inputs. Using number only switches the default view of the keyboard to the number view but you can still get back to the other keyboards. I tried using the pattern but I'm not sure if it's fully supported on all of the mobile browsers as it didn't restrict what I was typing in. Do you know if the validation is only done when the form is submitted?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input is saying the pattern is ignored if the type is not one of these: text, search, tel, url or email. Maybe try type="tel" with the pattern also